# Monotouch.Dialog Style Implementation Without Using Monotouch.Dialog?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

How would I go about implementing something in C# for iOS, that looks and feels like the MonoTouch.Dialog controls, without actually using Monotouch.Dialog?

Comment: Go, check the source of MT.Dialog (https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) and then implement it differently. Not sure why you would want to do that, though.

Comment: What I mean is, if I were coding for example a Settings page, but using Objective C, it would be very straightforward to make it look like the Settings app in iOS. I can do the same using MonoTouch.Dialog, but I've had problems with the EntryElements not always working, so I wanted to know how to get that look/feel/functionality of the settings page, using C Sharp, but not using Monotouch.Dialog....if there's a way without writing loads and loads of code? Or is that the point? i.e. Is Monotouch.Dialog there because without using it, it's a lot of work to get that Settings style implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same amount of code if you use ObjC or Xamarin.iOS. Just slightly different syntax.

Your alternatives are

- MT.Dialog (if you want to do the UI in code). This will dramatically reduce the complexity and MT.Dialog was designed exactly for the creation of quick and simple settings screens. In most cases, you will want to subclass the predefined elements to get best results.
- Static `UITableViewCells` if you want to use Interface Builder. This allows you to create your UI in IB (or the iOS Designer built into Xamarin Studio). You can find tutorials on the web, like [this one](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/05/07/static-table-views-with-storyboards.html).

Comment: So ultimately if I write the whole thing in code, without using IB and without using MT.Dialog, then the easiest way to make it look and feel like the usual iOS Settings app, is to use tables?

Comment: Exactly. But that's the most inconvenient way.